# Acomodar valores de JSON en CSV por Posición en Python

Tags: python, csv

Estoy haciendo un programa para poder visualizar los datos obtenidos por una base de datos en formato CSV, a partir de un JSON. Este es un fragmento de mi JSON:

```
"Cobranza" : {
"R6 y R9 Teodoro" : {
  "-KzgOWUK5FtUmpDQ8kC5" : "",
  "-KzgOWUgcwDKjFO1kH2J" : "",
  "-KzgOWUhNaIsoerLz2si" : "",
  "-KzgOWUj_zUYPy5Ul5Uy" : "Mi ubicacion actual es:   ",
  "-KzgOWVe9U9OeZZid20c" : "11:00 p.m.23, noviembre del 2017"
},
"R7 y R11 Jose Luis RB" : {
  "-Kw1uon1_xFt_rX252FT" : "999",
  "-Kw1uon47lxHH1PJw-cl" : "9999",
  "-Kw1uon47lxHH1PJw-cm" : "prueba",
  "-Kw1uon47lxHH1PJw-cn" : "",
  "-Kw1uon5KdOOwAHQxYvW" : "3:54 PM9, octubre del 2017",
  "-Kzg8BMnaPQ7w-eP6bFr" : "123",
  "-Kzg8BMxnyRNs_cI9K3p" : "123",
  "-Kzg8BN-g1A286AhlDLU" : "",
  "-Kzg8BN1D_-KejRLz6Yb" : "",
  "-Kzg8BN2c3d8bBAvXsw_" : "9:48 PM23, noviembre del 2017",
  "-Kzk82J2TKqY7INSEaSL" : "10200",
  "-Kzk82JKMEQNchR4_t0G" : "100",
  "-Kzk82JKMEQNchR4_t0H" : "",
  "-Kzk82JL4SCZyiPiz7c9" : "Localizacion agregada",
  "-Kzk82JL4SCZyiPiz7cA" : "4:26 PM24, noviembre del 2017",
  "-Kzk86MTTVJalcKPYVZV" : "1233",
  "-Kzk86MUEVNfm8b_KD9W" : "85",
  "-Kzk86MVxeggh5UbNeRq" : "",
  "-Kzk86MYoNvXA6c16gJi" : "Localizacion agregada",
  "-Kzk86MYoNvXA6c16gJj" : "4:26 PM24, noviembre del 2017",
  "-KzkR2WOCdwrvt-ylh3w" : "12000",
  "-KzkR2WYvR5lX9RVb570" : "70",
  "-KzkR2WZN76ZQmoOmF4L" : "",
  "-KzkR2WZN76ZQmoOmF4M" : "Mi ubicacion actual es:   ",
  "-KzkR2WZN76ZQmoOmF4N" : "5:49 PM24, noviembre del 2017",
```

Hasta ahora tengo este código

```
import json
import csv
infile = open("firebase.json","r",)
ou = open("firebaseLUL.csv","w",)
c=json.loads(infile.read(),encoding='utf8')
writer = csv.writer(ou)
writer.writerow (["","Cobrador","Folio","Monto","nota","ubicacion","Fecha"])
for row in c["Cobranza"]:
writer.writerow(["Cobranza",row.encode('utf-8')])
```

Mi pregunta es, ¿Cómo puedo seleccionar los datos de cada posición de item para que se acomoden en una tabla en este formato en el CSV:

```
("","Cobrador","Folio","Monto","nota","ubicacion","Fecha")
```

Tomando en cuenta qué :

```
"Cobranza" : {
"R6 y R9 Teodoro" : { ------Cobrador
  "-KzgOWUK5FtUmpDQ8kC5" : "", ----- Folio
  "-KzgOWUgcwDKjFO1kH2J" : "", ------ Monto
  "-KzgOWUhNaIsoerLz2si" : "", -------Nota
  "-KzgOWUj_zUYPy5Ul5Uy" : "Mi ubicacion actual es: ", ----Ubicación
  "-KzgOWVe9U9OeZZid20c" : "11:00 p.m.23, noviembre del 2017" --- Fecha
},
```

Y los datos siempre siguen el mismo patrón

Comment: Segun el ejemplo de entrada que muestras que valores corresponden a "Cobrador","Folio","Monto","nota","ubicacion","Fecha"?

Comment: Tomando este fragmento como referencia
"R6 y R9 Teodoro" : { ---------------------------- Este es el Cobrador
  "-KzgOWUK5FtUmpDQ8kC5" : "", --------------- Folio
  "-KzgOWUgcwDKjFO1kH2J" : "", ----------------Monto
  "-KzgOWUhNaIsoerLz2si" : "", --------------------- Nota
  "-KzgOWUj_zUYPy5Ul5Uy" : "Mi ubicacion actual es:   ", ------ Ubicación
  "-KzgOWVe9U9OeZZid20c" : "11:00 p.m.23, noviembre del 2017" -----------Fecha

Siempre los datos seguiran el mismo patrón

Comment: Luis edita tu pregunta añadelo alli, entiende que nosotros no pensamos igual que tu, no estamos en tu cabeza.

Comment: Lo siento, Ya intenté explicarme un poco mejor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El archivo .json que muestras no es un json valido, pienso que es causado porque lo has copiado de forma incorrecta. Yo asumire que el .json debe de tener el siguiente formato:

```
{
    "Cobranza": {
        "R6 y R9 Teodoro": {
            "-KzgOWUK5FtUmpDQ8kC5": "",
            "-KzgOWUgcwDKjFO1kH2J": "",
            "-KzgOWUhNaIsoerLz2si": "",
            "-KzgOWUj_zUYPy5Ul5Uy": "Mi ubicacion actual es:   ",
            "-KzgOWVe9U9OeZZid20c": "11:00 p.m.23, noviembre del 2017"
        },
        "R7 y R11 Jose Luis RB": {
            "-Kw1uon1_xFt_rX252FT": "999",
            "-Kw1uon47lxHH1PJw-cl": "9999",
            "-Kw1uon47lxHH1PJw-cm": "prueba",
            "-Kw1uon47lxHH1PJw-cn": "",
            "-Kw1uon5KdOOwAHQxYvW": "3:54 PM9, octubre del 2017",
            "-Kzg8BMnaPQ7w-eP6bFr": "123",
            "-Kzg8BMxnyRNs_cI9K3p": "123",
            "-Kzg8BN-g1A286AhlDLU": "",
            "-Kzg8BN1D_-KejRLz6Yb": "",
            "-Kzg8BN2c3d8bBAvXsw_": "9:48 PM23, noviembre del 2017",
            "-Kzk82J2TKqY7INSEaSL": "10200",
            "-Kzk82JKMEQNchR4_t0G": "100",
            "-Kzk82JKMEQNchR4_t0H": "",
            "-Kzk82JL4SCZyiPiz7c9": "Localizacion agregada",
            "-Kzk82JL4SCZyiPiz7cA": "4:26 PM24, noviembre del 2017",
            "-Kzk86MTTVJalcKPYVZV": "1233",
            "-Kzk86MUEVNfm8b_KD9W": "85",
            "-Kzk86MVxeggh5UbNeRq": "",
            "-Kzk86MYoNvXA6c16gJi": "Localizacion agregada",
            "-Kzk86MYoNvXA6c16gJj": "4:26 PM24, noviembre del 2017",
            "-KzkR2WOCdwrvt-ylh3w": "12000",
            "-KzkR2WYvR5lX9RVb570": "70",
            "-KzkR2WZN76ZQmoOmF4L": "",
            "-KzkR2WZN76ZQmoOmF4M": "Mi ubicacion actual es:   ",
            "-KzkR2WZN76ZQmoOmF4N": "5:49 PM24, noviembre del 2017"
        }
    }
}
```

para separarlo usaremos la clase csv y json, este retorna un diccionario, e iteramos a traves del key o value asociado segun sea el caso.

```
import json
import csv

data = json.load(open('data.json'))
f = open("output.csv", 'w')
writer = csv.writer(f)
writer.writerow(("Cobrador","Folio","Monto","nota","ubicacion","Fecha"))
for key, value in data["Cobranza"].items():
    val = list(value.values())
    for i in range(0, len(val), 5):
        writer.writerow([key] + val[i:i+5])
```

Salida:

```
Cobrador,Folio,Monto,nota,ubicacion,Fecha
R6 y R9 Teodoro,,,,Mi ubicacion actual es:   ,"11:00 p.m.23, noviembre del 2017"
R7 y R11 Jose Luis RB,999,9999,prueba,,"3:54 PM9, octubre del 2017"
R7 y R11 Jose Luis RB,123,123,,,"9:48 PM23, noviembre del 2017"
R7 y R11 Jose Luis RB,10200,100,,Localizacion agregada,"4:26 PM24, noviembre del 2017"
R7 y R11 Jose Luis RB,1233,85,,Localizacion agregada,"4:26 PM24, noviembre del 2017"
R7 y R11 Jose Luis RB,12000,70,,Mi ubicacion actual es:   ,"5:49 PM24, noviembre del 2017"
```

Imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda, es justo lo que necesitaba!! , y sí, el Json estaba mal ya que solo era un fragmento de el archivo completo. De nuevo, Gracias.

Comment: @LuisAlejandroBc Trata de ser preciso en tus preguntas, como repito no asumas cosas porque no estamos en tu cabeza.